# Junit Tests failing when running it through jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jenkins

I am getting the following error when I am running my Tests in Jenkins. They run fine in Eclipse.

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in SCSystemTestCase
```

SCSystemTestCase is a class which extends TestCase and is used by other Junit Tests to run tests. Snippet of SCSystemTestCase is as shown below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.AssertionFailedError;

import org.jtestcase.JTestCase;
import org.jtestcase.JTestCaseException;
import org.jtestcase.TestCaseInstance;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SCSystemTestCase extends TestCase
{

  protected HashMap<String, Vector<String>> params = null;
  protected String testCaseFName = "";
  protected String testGoal = "";
  protected String testCaseFFolder = "";
  protected String testCaseClass = "";
  protected String testCaseLocationprefix = "SC";
  protected String testCaseLocation = "";
  protected String jerseyEndpoint = "";
  protected String requestMethod = "";
  protected String requestPath = "";
  protected String responseData = "";
  protected String description = "";
  protected String dataDir = "";
  protected String testCaseName;
  protected String testCaseMethod;
  protected TestCaseInstance testCaseCur;  
  protected Vector<?> testCases = null;

  private JTestCase thisJtestCase; 

  public SCSystemTestCase(String s, String t)
  {
    super(s);
    testCaseName = s;
    testCaseMethod = t;

  }

  public SCSystemTestCase(String s)
  {    
    super(s);
  }

  public SCSystemTestCase()
  {
  }

  public void setup() throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      testCaseLocation = testCaseFFolder + File.separator + testCaseFName;
      setThisJtestCase(new JTestCase(testCaseLocation, testCaseClass));
    }
    catch (JTestCaseException jte)
    {
      System.out.println(jte.getMessage());
    }
  }


  @Override
  protected void runTest() throws Throwable
  {
    setup();
    triggerTest();
  }

  @Test
  protected void triggerTest() throws Exception
  {
    StringBuffer errorBucket = new StringBuffer();
   Hashtable<?,?> globalParams = null;
   // Hashtable<String, String> globalParams = null;
    try
    {
      testCases = getThisJtestCase().getTestCasesInstancesInMethod(testCaseMethod);
      globalParams = getThisJtestCase().getGlobalParams();
      jerseyEndpoint =  (String) globalParams.get("jerseyEndpoint");
      requestMethod =   (String) globalParams.get("requestMethod");
      requestPath =     (String) globalParams.get("requestPath");
      dataDir =         (String) globalParams.get("dataDir");

      for (int i = 0; i < testCases.size(); i++)
      {

        testCaseCur = (TestCaseInstance) testCases.elementAt(i);
        if (testCaseCur.getTestCaseName().equals(testCaseName))
        {
          System.out.println("Starting test: " + testCaseCur.getTestCaseName());
          System.out.println("======================================================");
          params = testCaseCur.getTestCaseParams();
          testGoal = (String) ((params.get("testGoal") != null) ? params.get("testGoal") : " Not Specified ");
          System.out.println("TEST-GOAL: " + testGoal);
          boolean isNegative = (Boolean) ((params.get("isNegative") != null) ? params.get("isNegative") : false);

          try
          {
            XMLDataParser test = new XMLDataParser();
            test.testExecuteTestSteps(params);
          }
          catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
            if (!isNegative)
            {
              System.out.println("It is NOT a negative test, why did it throw an Exception!");
              errorBucket.append("\n-----" + testCaseMethod + "." + testCaseCur.getTestCaseName() + "-----");
              errorBucket.append("\nIt is NOT a negative test, why did it throw an Exception!\n");
            }
            else
            {
              System.out.println("It is a negative test!");
            }
          }
          finally
          {
            System.out.println("--Ending test: " + testCaseCur.getTestCaseName() + "--");
          }
        }
      }

    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      System.out.println("======================================================");
    }

    if (errorBucket.length() > 0)
    {
      throw new AssertionFailedError(errorBucket.toString());
    }

  }

//  protected abstract void testExecuteTestSteps() throws Exception, Throwable;


  public JTestCase getThisJtestCase()
  {
    return thisJtestCase;
  }

  public void setThisJtestCase(JTestCase thisJtestCase)
  {
    this.thisJtestCase = thisJtestCase;
  }
```

Could you please help me resolve this? This class does not have its own TestSuite() or tests. build.gradle file and eclipse both are using Junit4.10. There are no @Test annotations in any of the tests which extend this.Do I need to change the junit version in the gradle file to junit 3? If yes, which version should I use?

Comment: You're running them *how*?

Comment: Using the gradle build command on the jenkins server.

Comment: When you have a class that extends TestCase, I usually figure we're talking about JUnit 3 and yet here you have both "extends TestCase" and methods annotated with @Test, which implies JUnit 4. I would not try to mix JUnit 3 and 4 in the same class. When you say the test runs locally, do you mean you are running the test locally within your IDE, or locally using Gradle? Clearly you see an error on your build server, which I assume is using Gradle.

Comment: I see the error even when I run it locally on gradle but not in the IDE. I did run the testst in gradle by removing @Test annotation in SCSystemTestCase vut that didnt resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You mix JUnit 3 and JUnit 4. I think that Eclipse chooses to run your test as JUnit 4 test and Gradle decides that it is a JUnit 3 test. This is the reason for the different behaviour.

If you want to use JUnit 3, than you have to change the `SCSystemTestCase`

- Rename the method `setup` as `setUp`
- Delete the `runTest` method (it must not be overridden according to its Javadoc)
- Remove the `@Test` annotation
- Rename the method `triggerTest` as `testSomething` (it's important that the methods name starts with `test`).
- In general a JUnit 3 test must not import any class of the `org.junit` package or one of its sub-packages.

But I strongly recommend using JUnit 4. For this you have to change the `SCSystemTestCase`

- Remove the `extends TestCase` part of your class declaration
- Remove the `super` calls in your constructors
- Delete the `runTest` method.
- Every test class (a class that inherits from `SCSystemTestCase`) must have a default constructor (a constructor without arguments)
- In general a JUnit 4 test must not import any class of the `junit.framework` package or one of its sub-packages.